# how to concatenate strings with the lines of a text file

Tags: text, cmd, concatenation

I've been trying to concatenate strings with the lines of a text file, but something is wrong with my code and I belive is the agruments I am using in the the For cycle. If any one can help me I'll much appreciate it.

My code is:

```
@echo off
set "input=C:\Users\123\Desktop\List.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%F in ("%input%") do (
        set "str1=C:\some directory\"
    set "str2=%%~F"
    set "str3=.pdf"
    set "str4=%str1%%str2%%str3%"
    echo.%str4%
)
```

and the text file is something like:

```
121122
122233
123344
124455
```

But I am only getting a wrong answer and I have to run it like 3 times to get a real result and it's wrong, the first two are blank spaces and the third one gives back the last line in the text file but repeated n times where, n is the number of lines in the text file.

Result:

```
C:\Users\123\Desktop>concatenate.bat





C:\Users\123\Desktop>concatenate.bat





C:\Users\123\Desktop>concatenate.bat
C:\some directory\124455.pdf
C:\some directory\124455.pdf
C:\some directory\124455.pdf
C:\some directory\124455.pdf
C:\some directory\124455.pdf

C:\Users\123\Desktop>
```

So, if any one has a clue on what is wrong please let me know.

Regards

-Victor-

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the *Enable Delayed Expansion* feature. It's required since within a `FOR` command block, you need to refer variables that was modified.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=C:\Users\123\Desktop\List.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%F in ("%input%") do (
    set "str1=C:\some directory\"
    set "str2=%%~F"
    set "str3=.pdf"
    set "str4=!str1!!str2!!str3!!"
    echo. !str4!
)
```